# Angular HTTP request get response body

Tags: angular, http, request, response

I am currently trying to figure out how to get the response body. I can see it in the browser's network console as an array of strings(this is what i would like to get) but using my code will only return an Object:

```
this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
            } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
                console.log('resp: ' + event.body);
            }
          });
```

It is an POST request.

This is the log:

```
resp: [object Object]
```

Comment: when you print the event (without .body) what do you get ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use JSON.stringify to see the actual content

```
 console.log('resp: ' + JSON.stringify(event.body));
```

if you want to access particular field from the response, use JSON.parse to convert to Object

```
let filename = (JSON.parse(event.body)).fileName;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Saved me a lot of times.Have a nice day bro

Comment: Couldn't marked it that fast. I will. Do you also happen to know how to get a certain response parameter from that ? like 'fileName' ?

Comment: you have to use JSON.parse(event.body)

Comment: and then access using dot operator